# Is it positive that a reference was checked after an interview?

Tags: interviewing, hiring-process, references

A couple of weeks ago, I interviewed for a job and I was told I didn't get it.

But this week I got an email from one of my references saying that he was requested to send his feedback about me.

Is that a good sign?

Comment: It means the hiring process is still on-going and they're at the point of checking your references. It might mean something, and it might not.

Comment: You say "I don't get it". Do you mean you were told you hadn't got the job? Or that you haven't heard about it yet?

Comment: I had email from them saying  they selected another candidate for this position.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This could mean that the person they first chose was not the best person for the position and you may of been second choice, so they are doing more background checking prior to offering you the position. Yes I would take this as a positive thing I would think.

Answer (score 5):

> But this week I got an email from one of my references saying that he
>   was requested to send his feedback about me.
>
> Is that a good sign?

It depends on the timing.

If your reference was contacted before the company made its decision, then it's not a good sign.

If your reference was contacted after the company made its decision, then perhaps the first choice fell through and you are the next best choice. That could be a good sign (assuming you want to be hired by this company).

Answer (score 1):

It might be a good sign - there are a few possiblities here.

- The job has not been taken yet, and you are still being considered for the part.  Either the person who you thought got the job didn't turn out to qualify as well as they'd liked, or you misinterpreted their response at the end of your interview, and came out more favorably than you realized.
- They are sharing your information cross-departmentally to see if anyone else might want to hire you for a job, which means you may have a chance to work with another department of the same organization.
- The reference is just now getting back to you about it, after the interview process is complete.
- They've referenced you to a different company, which is currently undergoing a screening proccess.

At this stage, you cannot know which of these things might be true.  Keep an eye on your inbox and mailbox, and watch for phone calls in the near future - you may be in a better positiont han you think.